# find does not descend to some directories

Tags: bash, find

`find .` should, according to my knowledge print out recursively everything in the current directory, however when I use it in a directory I'm getting the following

```
.
./WORKSPACE
./bazel-out
./lib
./lib/BUILD
./lib/hello-time.h
./lib/hello-time.cc
./main
./main/BUILD
./main/hello-world.cc
./main/hello-greet.h
./main/hello-greet.cc
./bazel-stage3
./bazel-bin
./bazel-testlogs
./README.md
./bazel-genfiles
```

however, this is not everything -- at least the folder `bazel-bin` contains some files. Actually, if I run `find bazel-bin`, this is what I get:

```
bazel-bin/
bazel-bin/lib
bazel-bin/lib/_objs
bazel-bin/lib/_objs/hello-time
bazel-bin/lib/_objs/hello-time/hello-time.pic.d
bazel-bin/lib/_objs/hello-time/hello-time.pic.o
bazel-bin/lib/libhello-time.a
bazel-bin/lib/libhello-time.a-2.params
bazel-bin/main
bazel-bin/main/_objs
bazel-bin/main/_objs/hello-greet
bazel-bin/main/_objs/hello-greet/hello-greet.pic.o
bazel-bin/main/_objs/hello-greet/hello-greet.pic.d
bazel-bin/main/_objs/hello-world
bazel-bin/main/_objs/hello-world/hello-world.pic.o
bazel-bin/main/_objs/hello-world/hello-world.pic.d
bazel-bin/main/libhello-greet.so
bazel-bin/main/hello-world.runfiles_manifest
bazel-bin/main/libhello-greet.so-2.params
bazel-bin/main/hello-world-2.params
bazel-bin/main/libhello-greet.a-2.params
bazel-bin/main/hello-world.runfiles
bazel-bin/main/hello-world.runfiles/__main__
bazel-bin/main/hello-world.runfiles/__main__/main
bazel-bin/main/hello-world.runfiles/__main__/main/hello-world
bazel-bin/main/hello-world.runfiles/MANIFEST
bazel-bin/main/libhello-greet.a
bazel-bin/main/hello-world
```

Why the `find .` does not descend into bazel-bin?

Thank you.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I just tried this on my local system and it did work recursively.  I am using Suse...

Comment: @Jason what do you mean you tried it? You don’t have the same file structure unless you downloaded the bazel tutorial and compiled it. For me it descends to some folders and not to others.

Comment: Oh sorry.  I see that now.  At a glance, it looked like you had no recursive behavior at all.

Comment: Is `bezel-bin` a link? `find .` won't follow links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bet is that `bezel-bin` is a soft link within your current directory.

Find will not traverse the soft link. You should try `find . -follow`

Comment: Exactly. Thank you.